# Should inheritance be used when sub-entities have the same attributes (ER-diagrams)?

Tags: database, inheritance, entity-relationship

I was wondering, when modeling a database, should inheritance be used if the sub-entities have the exact same attributes?

Let me explain with an example. In competitions for weightlifting, weightlifters do two different moves: "Snatch", and "Clean and jerk". They have three tries for each move. I modeled this in the following way:

[image]

At first, it made sense to me, because the two moves have a lot of attributes in common, which are in the parent-entity called Result. However, "Snatch" and "CleanAndJerk" also have completely equal attributes. This seems redundant. Though, it does not seem much better to place everything in the "Result"-entity either.

Is this a good choice when designing a database?

Comment: there are still things that you can do to make this design better. but the answer only targeted your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situations what you really need is a polymorphic table.

I think it's better if you do it this way:

1. `Move` table. columns: `FirstTry`,`SecondTry`,`ThirdTry`,`BestTry`,`MoveTypeId`.
2. `MoveType` table. columns: `MoveTypeId`,`MoveTypeName`,`MoveTypeDescription`.

then simple the `Move` has a Foreign Key to `MoveType` table.

Comment: Omg, you are a genius! Thank you so much :D that was a much more elegant solution, and I really like how you noticed that it should be solved by polymorphism right away.

I just noticed you said there was more I could do to make the design better, any fast suggestions?

Comment: well really thanks, but any other person could have answered the same. the other question that you can ask concerning the design is that "what if there is a FourthTry?" then what happens? you can of course correct this too so that your database can handle arbitrary number of tries. i think you can handle this yourself though.

Comment: just think about the new problem here. if you needed help just comment here and i will edit my answer. tnx.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that also now :) you are right, if more attempts are added, then more rows need to be added, and that would not be good